# Cannot add @name at the beginning of a comment in an answer

Tags: support, comments

I want to comment [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/186499/47206) asking for more help, but cannot add the `@name-of-user` - the user that my comment is addressed to. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in this case, the user is also the post owner - the post owner *always* gets notified of comments on their question.